# Code gives missing 1 required positional argument error

Tags: python, tkinter, glob

This code gives the error:

```
TypeError: otsi() missing 1 required positional argument: 'x'
```

The code is supposed to open a .pdf file by a part of its name, which I input to the Tellimus_entry.

```
Tellimus_entry = Entry(ws)
Tellimus_entry.grid(row=4,column=3,padx=(10, 10), sticky=(N, S, E, W), columnspan=3)


def otsi(x):
    return glob.glob(f'C:/Users/ASUS/Desktop/Proov/*{x}*.pdf')

    otsitav = Tellimus_entry.get()
    files = otsi(otsitav)
    print(files)
    if files:
        os.startfile(files[0])
nupp = ttk.Button(ws, text="Ava tellimuse PDF", command=otsi)
nupp.grid(row=3,column=3, sticky=(N, S, E, W), pady=5, padx=5)
```

Comment: Please update the indentation of your code. Python is very sensitive to indentation, as are python programmers.

Comment: You are calling otsi here in the command without any argument. `nupp = ttk.Button(ws, text="Ava tellimuse PDF", command=otsi)`

Comment: @quamrana which indentation? you mean otsitav = Tellimus_entry.get()?

Comment: Yes, that was my assumption simply because no one normally puts any code after a `return`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your description in your question, actually the argument `x` of `otsi()` is not necessary:

```py
def otsi():
    otsitav = Tellimus_entry.get()
    files = glob.glob(f'C:/Users/ASUS/Desktop/Proov/*{otsitav}*.pdf')
    print(files)
    if files:
        os.startfile(files[0])
```

Answer (score 2):

You can pass the command argument as a lambda, this way the `x` parameter you need wont be missing

```py
Tellimus_entry = Entry(ws)
Tellimus_entry.grid(row=4,column=3,padx=(10, 10), sticky=(N, S, E, W), columnspan=3)


def otsi(x):
    return glob.glob(f'C:/Users/ASUS/Desktop/Proov/*{x}*.pdf')

    otsitav = Tellimus_entry.get()
    files = otsi(otsitav)
    print(files)
    if files:
        os.startfile(files[0])
nupp = ttk.Button(ws, text="Ava tellimuse PDF", command=lambda: otsi(whatever_param_you_need))
nupp.grid(row=3,column=3, sticky=(N, S, E, W), pady=5, padx=5)
```